# cancel build operation

Tags: build-process, continuous-integration, build-automation, hudson

I am in phase of implementing hudson for the build automation. I am using some shell scripts to perform one of the build step. Cancel build operation (in the middle of build process) leads to the build in illogical state. Is it possible to restrict users to use cancel build operation?

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off having the build make a clean workspace on each build. Having prior exit state be a factor in the stability of the build is likely to lead to more problems.

Even if you have the *Use custom workspace* option enabled and have a special set up for the build, consider having the first step of the build be a script that cleans up any prior artifacts and build steps that might have been created by failed builds.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning up the workspace is not an problem, but I use some scripts to checkout and change source code in cleacase prior to package. And if somebody abort it in between, those files could remain checked out and in invalid state. Hence I need users to not use abort build operation in the middle of the process. Thanks.